# Vue.js store data as dictionary using v-model

Tags: vue.js

I have

```
<v-switch
         v-model="Books" v-for="option in options"
         :value="option.id" :label="option.display_name"
         :key="option.id"
         :disabled="disabled"
         color="primary" dense hoverable>
</v-switch>
```

and

```
export default{
     name: Books
     data: () => ({
         Books: [] 
      })
}
```

I want to store my data as objects where option.id is the key, and inside you have id and presence. If the switch wasn't selected that presence is null

```
"97":{"id":"97","presence":"1"},
 "98":{"id":"98","presence":"1"},
 "99":{"id":"99","presence":null},
```

How would I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
const arrayToObject = (array, keyField) =>
   array.reduce((obj, item) => {
     obj[item[keyField]] = item
     return obj
   }, {})
const convertedBooks = arrayToObject(books, "id")
```

This is a common problem, and there a lot of articles that guide you on how to convert an array to a dictionary, for example here is [one](https://medium.com/dailyjs/rewriting-javascript-converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-object-ec579cafbfc7)